# XPC Service and AVFoundation

Tags: macos, cocoa, opencv, avfoundation, osx-yosemite

Is it possible to use AVFoundation and OpenCV inside an XPC service?
I have such a simple code

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface AppDelegate(){
    cv::VideoCapture m_vidCap;
}
```

...

```
//Hacky way of forcing OpenCV to call AVFoundation for the first time
    //before the camera arrives
    //OpenCV should add a better way of mapping camera indexes to cameras
    //This way we force that devices are enumerated in the same order here
    //and in their code
    m_vidCap.open(-1);
    m_vidCap.release();
[AVCaptureDevice devices]; //Force avfoundation "startup"
@autoreleasepool {
    std::vector<std::wstring> devices;
    // chosen device.
    NSArray *osDevices=[AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    NSStringEncoding encoding    =   CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding ( kCFStringEncodingUTF32LE );
    AVCaptureDevice *device;
    int did=0;
    for(device in osDevices) {
        NSString *deviceName=[device localizedName];
        NSData* wstrdata  = [deviceName dataUsingEncoding : encoding ];
        std::wstring cppDeviceName=std::wstring((wchar_t*) [ wstrdata bytes ], [ wstrdata length] / sizeof ( wchar_t ) );
        devices.push_back(cppDeviceName);
        //NSLog("Device %d: %S at position %ld",did,cppDeviceName.c_str(),device.position);
        did++;
    }
}
```

that works as needed when started inside a regular Cocoa application. It will enumerate both cameras, the FaceTime one and an USB one.

If I place the same exact code inside my XPC service it will hang forever at

```
m_vidCap.open(-1);
```

and will never execute further.

I'm assuming there are some limitation about what can be used inside an XPC service, but I could not google anything useful.
Any input is much appreciated.
Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after lots of tries and checking samples from apple I've got it working. The problem was how the `NSXPCListener` gets created.
Before I had it like a regular service

```
NSXPCListener *listener = [NSXPCListener serviceListener];
```

which didn't work.

After I changed to

```
ToolMonitorDelegate *myDelegate = [[ToolMonitorDelegate alloc] initWithHardwareType:HT_Vision];
NSXPCListener *listener = [[NSXPCListener alloc] initWithMachServiceName:bundleId];

listener.delegate = myDelegate;
[listener resume];

[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];
```

everything worked immediately. 
Looks to me like the OpenCV needs to have running app loop in order to work properly. Correct me if I'm wrong or there is another explication.

Comment: Are you using a LaunchAgent or LaunchDaemon? I solved a similar problem in a standard XPCService by using your approach but it only works when running from Xcode. When launching the application outside Xcode it seems that connecting to the service fails.

Comment: at the end I gave using XPC service and OpenCV, everything was working very unstable, lots of exceptions where they can't just happen. After I moved all OpenCV code into main application all worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there! I think AVFoundation needs to use an `NSRunLoop`, but XPC services use `dispatch_main` by default. You need to add a key to the dictionary value identified by the `XPCService` key in the XPC service's `info.plist` file. By default it should have a single `ServiceType` key. Add a `RunLoopType` key, and give it a string value of `NSRunLoop`.

For more info, see [Creating XPC services](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingXPCServices.html).